# Why this objective-c singleton works?

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I have create a singleton of Objective-C like this as find on the internet tutorial:

```
+(id) sharedInstance{
    static AdManager *manager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        manager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return manager;
}
```

Will the `static AdManager *manager` be released once the holder be released? 
and since the `*manager` is defined in a method scope rather than a field variable, will it be released too?

Then where will the object be held so it could be used next time we call `sharedInstance`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable declared as `static` within a method or function has global lifetime, but it is only visible by name within its declaring method/function.

As `manager` is a strong variable (by default) any object referenced by it will be owned by this variable either until the program terminates or a different reference (or `nil`) is assigned to `manager`.

HTH